# The first image of my Slick-Gallery changes the Layout of my webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, gallery, slick.js

I have 6 Images in my Slick gallery.
The first image is a bit off-center and it changes the layout of the page:
If we move from image 1 to image 2 the layout changes.
The layout of the page stays persistent through images 2-6 though.

[First image of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Cjo8.jpg)

[Second image of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKIqy.png)

I have tried changing my CSS around, but nothing seems to work

I'm very new to this so please let me know all the information you need for support!

CSS

```
.slick-slider-container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible; 
    height: auto;
    z-index: 10;
}

.slick-container, .paragraph-container {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible; 
}

.slick-container img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;  
    max-height: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    object-fit: contain;  
}

.some-wrapper {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="slick-container">

    <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext"> 1 / 7 </div>
        <img src="/media/slideshow gallery/ffxiv_dx11_2023-08-25_20-20-27.png" alt="">
        <span class="closeSlide" onclick="closeGallery()">X</span>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext"> 2 / 7 </div>
        <img src="/media/slideshow gallery/ffxiv_dx11_2023-08-25_20-33-26.png" alt="">
        <span class="closeSlide" onclick="closeGallery()">X</span>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext"> 3 / 7 </div>
        <img src="/media/slideshow gallery/ffxiv_dx11_2023-08-25_20-24-18.png" alt="">
        <span class="closeSlide" onclick="closeGallery()">X</span>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext"> 4 / 7 </div>
        <img src="/media/slideshow gallery/ffxiv_dx11_2023-08-25_20-18-20.png" alt="">
        <span class="closeSlide" onclick="closeGallery()">X</span>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext"> 5 / 7 </div>
        <img src="/media/slideshow gallery/ffxiv_dx11_2023-08-25_20-22-16.png" alt="">
        <span class="closeSlide" onclick="closeGallery()">X</span>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext"> 6 / 7 </div>
        <img src="/media/slideshow gallery/ffxiv_dx11_2023-08-25_20-18-42.png" alt="">
        <span class="closeSlide" onclick="closeGallery()">X</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  // Initialize the Slick carousel
  $('.slick-container').slick({
      centerMode: true,
      centerPadding: '0px',
      infinite: true,
      adaptiveHeight: true,
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      prevArrow: $('.prev'),
      nextArrow: $('.next')
  });
  
  $('.slick-container').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});

  // Add the enlarged class to the initial center slide
  $('.slick-container .slick-current').addClass('enlarged');

  // Handle beforeChange event
  $('.slick-container').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
      // Remove the enlarged class from the current center slide
      $('.slick-container .slick-slide').removeClass('enlarged');
      // Add the enlarged class to the next center slide
      $(slick.$slides[nextSlide]).next().addClass('enlarged');
  });

  function closeGallery() {
      $('.slick-container').slick('unslick'); // Uninitialize slick when closing the gallery if needed
  }

  // If you still need other event bindings, place them here

});
```

I tried changing things in the CSS Code.
I tried changing things inside of the JS code as well.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The entire set of 5 images is jogged leftward slightly (in your image example 4Cjo8). Nothing obvious in the shown CSS. The only thing I can suggest is perhaps testing a different JS setup. Welcome to SO.